# How to get WSL2 to route traffic through ProxyCap ssh tunnel

Tags: proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to get WSL2 to use the tunnel present in my windows environment but I'm struggling with getting it to work properly.

In order to access our company servers I've set up ProxyCap to open a ssh connection to a proxy server. The only thing I did was point it to our jump server and then set up the following rule.
[image: ProxyCap Routing Rule]

Now this works flawlessly in Windows and I'm able to ping a machine inside our company network by doing a simple `ping x.x.x.x:pppp`. However once I start my WSL2 environment and try pinging the same ip and port the only thing I get back is `ping: ping x.x.x.x:pppp: Name or service not known`.

My initial guess is that this is due to the network in WSL2 being different from the network in Windows. Is there any way to make WSL2 utilize the proxy tunnel running in my Windows environment?

I've also tried running sshuttle inside WSL2 to see if I could access the server that way and not have to go through Windows (I'm using the same command I use on my Linux machine where it works) but I get the same problem this way.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with proxifier.

Comment: I have the same issue, only with windows commandline, not wsl.